# Extract mysql table column names with awk/grep and use awk to print xml

Tags: mysql, schema, awk

I have a mysql database,I want to have  an xml file in the end like so:

```
<user>
  <column>id</column>
  <column>name</column>
  <column>password</column>
</user>
<dept>
  <column>id</column>
  <column>name</column>
  <column>code</column>
</dept>
```

No doing the output formating part I'm sure i can do with awk or something but getting the column name from like a schema file . I 'm lost ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do this would be to use [mysqldump --xml option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml) - the output is different to what you outline above, but nothing you couldn't transform afterwards...here's how schema data might look for you (if you only want the schema, you'd also use --no-data)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="example">
<table_structure name="user">
<field Field="id" Type="int(11)" Null="NO" Key="PRI" Extra="auto_increment" />
<field Field="name" Type="varchar(128)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" />
<field Field="password" Type="varchar(128)" Null="NO" Key="" Default="" Extra="" />
</table_structure>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the table names:

```
Select `table_name` FROM `information_schema`.TABLES
```

and then from each table the columns:

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`;
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a text file with two fields: table_name and column name

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
```

then you can write a simple AWK script:

```
BEGIN {table_name = -1;}
    { 
      if (table_name != $1) {
          if (table_name != -1)
              printf("</%s>\n", table_name);
          table_name = $1;
          printf("<%s>\n", table_name);
      }
      printf("\t<column>%s</column>\n",$2);
    }
END { printf("</%s>\n", table_name); }
```